# In how many ways can eight rooks be placed on an 8 × 8-chessboard in such a way that no horizontal or vertical row contains two rooks?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

So apparently the answer for this $8!$, but I got $(8!)^2$. Here's what confuses me:

1. Take your first rook. You have $8\times 8$ positions to place it (each square of the chessboard is coordinated, so this means that each space is distinguished, right?)
2. Since each row and column can only have at most one rook, we are forced to discard the row and column of the first placed rook. This leaves a new  $7\times 7$-board.
3. Repeating step 1 and 2, we arrive at a total of
   $$8*8 * 7*7 *...*2*2*1*1= 8! *8!$$
   possible ways of placing each rook on the board.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Place $8$ rooks on a $10\times 10$ board.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2509485/place-8-rooks-on-a-10-times-10-board)

Comment: They seem to use the same method to get to $8!$. I want to stick with fixing my method, since it is more intuitive, at least to me.

Comment: Think of a $2 \times 2$ board. Your method double-counts the arrangement with one rook in the top left corner and one rook in the bottom right corner, since you count "doing the top left one before the bottom right one" and "doing the bottom right one before the top left one" separately.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct if each rook was uniquely identifiable so to speak. However if all rooks look the same then you are counting each combinatation $8!$ times.

Comment: Why is it $8!$?

Comment: Because any possible "swapping" of the positions of the rooks gives the same result, and there are $8!$ possible ways to swap them.

Comment: Got it, thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear that, my pleasure.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an edit to my answer based on @Asinomás 's response.

My original method actually answers the question in the following way:

*Given an order of 8 rooks, how many ways can they be placed on an $8\times 8$ chess board in such a way that no horizontal or vertical rows contain two rooks.*

The method above, gives $8! 8!$.

To answer the original question, means that I must consider all possible orders of the rooks (which is $8!$). Then truncate my original response to account for the repetitions:
$$\frac{8!8!}{8!}=8!$$